# Misspelled Hebrew words are not underlined in LibreOffice

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, language-support

Ubuntu 20.04.1, LibreOffice 6.4.6.2

Misspelled words in Hebrew (and in Arabic) are not underlined. However, I can see misspelled words through AutoCorrect function and its window (which can be called by F7) or when I click on it with right mouse button. Everything works fine for English, Russian, German. I set document's language as Hebrew, Automatic spell checking and AutoCorrect while typing are enabled. I even have downloaded a Hebrew spell checker for Libre, but that didn't help.
Even if I set Russian as a language of a document it doesn't underline words in Hebrew (but recently it did).

I don't know when this problem appeared because I have not typed anything in Libre in Hebrew since June. At that time misspelled words were always underlined.

Comment: Is the `hunspell-he` package installed on your system?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes, `hunspell-he is already the newest version (1:6.4.3-1)`

Answer (score 0):

I must tell you now: I have just upgraded to Libreoffice 7, and somehow, miraculously, it just worked. I have no idea why. So the bug is in 6 but not 7. Maybe they solved it. So just upgrade and try.